# Updating char[] field in a struct with strcpy. Pointer issue in C

Tags: c

I am wondering how i can set a struct's string value with a tokenized line from a file. basically i am reading in a line like `"Person 100 100"` (delimited by `\t`) and i need to set the string value of a struct with what's returned.

Error message:

```
||In function 'main':|
|32|warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\..\include\string.h|45|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char **'|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Code snippet:

```
char buffer[20];
fgets(buffer, 20, file);

while (*buffer != EOF)
{
    struct student temp;
    char *result = NULL;
    //set name
    strcpy(temp.name,strtok(buffer,"\t"));
    //set midterm
    result = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    temp.midterm = atoi(result);
    //set final
    result = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    temp.final = atoi(result);
}
```

Comment: It's telling you exactly what the error is - you're passing a `char **` where a `char *` is expected.  What's the definition of `struct student`?

Comment: Also, EOF doesn't work like that.

Comment: And `*buffer` is always looking at the same location anyway (it's the same as `buffer[0]`.

Comment: I understand the error, i just dont know how to remedy the char** issue.

Comment: @user1399792: dereference it once?! ...

Comment: Would you edit your original post and put just the source code that will allow a clearer view of the problem? tnx

Answer (score 1):

strcpy function is define as follows:

```
char *strcpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
```

do not know the student structure, so you may pass parameters error in the first parameters.  and below code is ok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    char name[128];
    int midterm;
    int final;
};

char buffer[] = {"Person    100 100"};
//fgets(buffer, 20, file);

int main()
{
    //while (*buffer != EOF)
    {
        struct student temp;
        char *result = NULL;
        //set name
        strcpy(temp.name,strtok(buffer,"\t"));
        //set midterm
        result = strtok(NULL, "\t");
        temp.midterm = atoi(result);
        //set final
        result = strtok(NULL, "\t");
        temp.final = atoi(result);
        printf("name = %s, midterm = %d, final = %d\n", temp.name, temp.midterm, temp.final);
    }

    return 0;
}
```